# In react how can you free a persisted event?

Tags: reactjs, events

If you need a react event persisted you can call event.persist().

Is there someway later when you are finished with the event to tell the event pool that it is no longer needed?

Comment: you probably don't need event.persist() at all, store what u need from the event in variables and use the variable as recommended by react event pool https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling  for performance reasons

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!

Comment: glad to hear I posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need event.persist() at all.

store what u need from the event in variables and use the variable as recommended by react event pool [reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling](http://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) for performance reasons